# Find CI for two norm distributions with both variances unknown

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid from $N(\mu,\sigma_1^2)$,   $Y_1,...,Y_m$  are iid from $N(\mu,\sigma_2^2)$. $X_i$ are independent of $Y_j$. Both $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are unknown. How to calculate CI for $\mu$?

Because two variances are unknown, and $n$ and $m$ are not necessarily equal, It's hard to find an appropriate statistic.

Comment: For starters, find a sufficient statistic for $\mu$. Presumably the $X_i$s are independent of the $Y_i$s.

Comment: Oh you are right. Any $x_i$ is independent of any $Y_i$. And $(\sum{X_i}, \sum{Y_i})$ should be sufficient for $\mu$. It's just hard to deal with two sigmas.

Comment: You should verify that $(\sum X_i+\sum Y_i,\sum X_i^2,\sum Y_i^2)$ is sufficient for $(\mu,\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2)$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom It clearly is not sufficient.

Comment: @JinbinShi Look at paper Nebojsa Marić & Franklin A. Graybill (1979) Evaluation of a method for setting confidence intervals on the common mean of two normal populations, Communications in Statistics - Simulation and Computation, 8:1, 53-60, DOI: 10.1080/03610917908812103

Comment: @NCh It's really helpful! I'll google it in a while. Thanks again!